# iOS App doesn't have a bundle identifier. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor

Tags: ios, .net, app-store, maui

I'm trying to publish an iOS .Net Maui to the App Store but this error shows up:

> The app doesn't have a bundle identifier. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor.

I've checked the Info.plist file and the CFBundleIdentifier is present with the correct values. I made sure distribution certificates and provisioning profiles are installed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Reinaldo

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found was to create a new .Net Maui project and copy all my code over.